# Reading from a network stream: packet fragmentation

Tags: .net, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream, fragmentation

I got a server that is managing two clients through `NetworkStream.Read`.

Application protocol is:

ClientMessage [128 Bytes] → Response from Server [128 Bytes]

Now at server-side: Is it possible, that `MyTcpClient.GetStream().Read()` returns only < 128 Bytes, although all messages from client-side are exactly 128 bytes long?

I guess that such a client message is short enough to fit into one packet on the tcp/ip layer - but could there be some kind of fragmentation or random although?

Is `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` the right attribute to defend against this?

After running smoothly for hours, i sometimes get strange errors and connection losses, that point to something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible, that MyTcpClient.GetStream().Read() returns only < 128 Bytes

Yes. You can't assume your call to Read( ) will return 128 bytes.

see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx):

> The total number of bytes read into
>   the buffer. This can be less than the
>   number of bytes requested if that many
>   bytes are not currently available, or
>   zero (0) if the end of the stream has
>   been reached.

See [this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html) link on how to properly read from streams

Try something like this instead: (pass in a 128 length byte array)

```
private static void ReadWholeArray (Stream stream, byte[] data)
    {
        int offset=0;
        int remaining = data.Length;
        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            int read = stream.Read(data, offset, remaining);
            if (read <= 0)
                throw new EndOfStreamException 
                    (String.Format("End of stream reached with {0} bytes left to read", remaining));
            remaining -= read;
            offset += read;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

**There is absolutely no guarantee** that you will receive the whole packet in one `Read` call, even if the packet was sent in one `Write` call, and it is smaller than the network MTU, and even if you are in fact sending to/reading from the loopback interface. You cannot do anything about this behavior.

The documentation for `Read` clearly states:

> An implementation is free to return
>   fewer bytes than requested even if the
>   end of the stream has not been
>   reached.

What you **can** do would go like this (pseudocode)

```
While (true) {
    Read from stream
    If bytes read == 0 {
        Socket was closed (buffer should be empty here)
        Break
    }
    Append read data to persistent buffer
    While (buffer.Length >= 128) {
        Extract first 128 bytes from buffer (buffer length now reduced by 128)
        Process message
    }
}
```

Comment: @Job, how can i process an uncomplete message ?