# how can I send an object over tcp socket to an android device?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a program written in java which acts as a type of server.  I need to send an object over this in a Tcp socket to the phone.

Before now I have just been communicsting string data via `PrintWriter` and `DataInputStream`.  I was going to try `ObjectInputStream` but I heard this might fail cross platform due to different java versions etc.  My object is serilizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a JSON serializer such as this one [here](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) to convert the object into a very readable string in whwich you could just use your normal PrintWriter system in place. You would just write the string out to the stream and then restore it on the other end. Simple.

Comment: And this all gets sent as one single line?  Is there anything like a socket string size limit per line I should be aware of which could complicate things?  I've never used JSON before

Comment: JSON is just a type of serialization - it's pretty popular. It doesn't contain Java version meta-data which makes it a popular candidate. You can also look at protobufs as well.

There's the MTU limit of a packet and there's the possbility of packets being fragmented but you should be handling this anyway in your code because TCP is a stream protocol. If you need more information on this, let me know.

Comment: Well considering without research I have no idea waht a protobuffer, MTU limit I'd say hook me up.  This should work for sending ArrayList<String> as an object as well correct?  Lastly do you mean that I need not worry about fragments or size limits because TCP's stream protocol is meant to inherently deal with those?  Thanks

Comment: The TCP protocol itself is a stream protocol. Packets are not necessarily going to arrive in one piece. You can see this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446409/reading-from-a-network-stream-packet-fragmentation for more information, the answers contain some more detailed explanations. This method will work for lists of objects as well; since JSON will naturally separate them up. How you parse this of course, is up to you.

The MTU limit is just the maximum size in bytes that a packet can be without it guaranteed to be broken up. You should generally keep packets smaller than this

Comment: What if it had to be larger?  Lets say a list or object contained more data than the MTU limit.  What then generally does one do?

Comment: In most cases, you don't need to worry about it... it'll be split up for you automatically. You just need to make sure on the RECIEVING end you actually handle it properly. In this case, you just keep reading until you've read the total amount of bytes needed. A lot of TCP implementations write the length of the packet as the first byte. 

TLDR: Don't worry about the MTU. It'll be handled for you if you can tolerate fragmentation and a couple extra sends and some latency.

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks, and if I might bug you for one last thing...  How about sending an image, audio,or video file over TCP sockets?  Basically, can it be done and is it not very difficult?

Comment: Sure, just send the raw bytes and re-create them on the client side. Your TCP packets might look something like this:

LENGTH (INT):  This is the length of the packet
PACKET_ID (BYTE): A unique ID for the packet incoming

Then based on the packet ID, you can do an action. So if you need to  parse images, you can perhaps define an enum with PACKET_TYPE.MEDIA_IMAGE and and then the client can read that out when the packet is finally parsed out. There's a lot of strategies, it's just one. Find what works best for you!